# Change is_front_page() to is_page() to display 'hero' on entire site?

Tags: functions, pages, sidebar

In the Velux theme `functions.php` there is this:

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_active_sidebar( 'hero' ) )
```

Which apparently means the Hero widget only functions on the home page. I used that widget to add custom HTML that needs to be in the header on all pages.

I tried the following mod to `functions.php` and cleared the cache, but cannot see the custom HTML on other site pages. Site is not yet public.

```
if ( is_page() && is_active_sidebar( 'hero' ) )
```

Comment: remove is_page() then hard refersh browser( ctrl+f5 ) and check

Comment: what is the code inside the if block?

Answer (score 0):

[`is_active_sidebar()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar) does not refer to a specific widget. It means if there is any widgets in your sidebar.

According to [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar):

> Any sidebar that contains widgets will return TRUE, whereas any
>   sidebar that does not contain any widgets will return FALSE.

Also, `is_page()` only works when the query has been run. It doesn't work at any points before that, you might want to check that out too. However since you are using `is_front_page()` I assume the query has already been run.

Comment: in is_active_sidebar( )  required Sidebar name or id due to wordpress documentation.

Comment: Yes. You should pass the sidebar's name.

Comment: The github solution was apparently an alternative method that bypassed `is_page()` and/or `is_front_page()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the successful answer from a developer on GitHub. I put this in my functions.php.

```
/**
 * Ensure the hero widget persists across all pages
 * @author GoDaddy
 */
function godaddy_persistent_hero() {
if ( is_front_page() || ! is_active_sidebar( 'hero' ) ) {
    return;
}
add_action( 'primer_after_site_header_wrapper', 'primer_add_hero' );
add_action( 'primer_hero', 'custom_velux_hero', 20 );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'godaddy_persistent_hero' );

/**
* Render the hero.
* @return mixed  Hero widget markup.
*/
function custom_velux_hero() {
dynamic_sidebar( 'hero' );
}
```